# guessing game in C# with 5 try

Tags: c#, for-loop

The guessing game allowed user to have 5 try, and if they don'g get it in 5 try then they lose. But on the fifth try, even if you get the answer right, the program still would say that you lose. Please can anyone tell me what I need to fix in my code to make it that on the fifth try you guess it right:; it will say "you win". Thank you.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Create an integer variable to hold a redom number
            int answer = 0;
            int guess = 0;

            //Creates an object of the Random class
            Random number = new Random();

            answer = number.Next(1, 11);
            //Creates for loop
            for (int i=1; i<=5; i++)
            {

                Console.Write("Enter Guess {0}:", i); 

                guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    if (i >= 5)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Your Lose.  The answer is {0}", answer);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (guess==answer)
                        {

                            Console.WriteLine("You Won!!    {0} is the correct number", answer);
                            break;
                        }

                        else if (guess < answer)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Guess is higher");
                        }

                        else if  (guess > answer)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Guess is lower");
                        }
                    }//end if
            }//end of for loop

            //Pause Display
            Console.ReadKey();
        }//end of Main**
```

Comment: `if (i > 5)` would be one place to start. right now you're allowing guesses 1,2,3,4 and immediately abort on guess 5. But sicne your for() loop would terminate on iteration #6 ANYWAYS, you should put the "too many guesses" outside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to put `if` statement before these lines:

```
Console.Write("Enter Guess {0}:", i); 
guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Try this:

```
for (int i=0; i<=5; i++)
{
   if (i == 5)
   {
        Console.WriteLine("Your Lose.  The answer is {0}", answer);
        break;
   }
    Console.Write("Enter Guess {0}:", i); 
    guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    if (guess==answer)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You Won!!    {0} is the correct number", answer);
        break;
    }
    else if (guess < answer)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Guess is higher");
    }
    else if  (guess > answer)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Guess is lower");
    }
}
```

Comment: dear there is no chance of `i>5` it can be `i==5` in for loop IMO

Comment: instead of setting i to 6 you can break from loop if it successful.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a variable which says wether search is successfull or not. at the end of the loop.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Create an integer variable to hold a redom number
        int answer = 0;
        int guess = 0;
        bool searchStatus=fale;
        //Creates an object of the Random class
        Random number = new Random();

        answer = number.Next(1, 11);
        //Creates for loop
        for (int i=1; i<=5; i++)
        {

            Console.Write("Enter Guess {0}:", i); 

            guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


                    if (guess==answer)
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine("You Won!!    {0} is the correct number", answer);
                        searchStatus=true;
                        break;
                    }

                    else if (guess < answer)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Guess is higher");
                    }

                    else if  (guess > answer)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Guess is lower");
                    }

        }//end of for loop

       if(!searchStatus)
       {
         Console.WriteLine("Your Lose.  The answer is {0}", answer);
       }

        //Pause Display
        Console.ReadKey();
    }//end of Main**
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to tweak a bit inside your `Main` method:

```
//Create an integer variable to hold a redom number
int answer = 0;
int guess = 0;

//Creates an object of the Random class
Random number = new Random();

answer = number.Next(1, 11);
//Creates for loop
for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
{

    if (i > 5)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your Lose.  The answer is {0}", answer);
        break;
    }

    Console.Write("Enter Guess {0}:", i);
    guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    if (guess == answer)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You Won!!    {0} is the correct number", answer);
        break;
    }
    else if (guess < answer)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Guess is lower");
    }
    else if (guess > answer)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Guess is higher");
    }
}//end of for loop

//Pause Display
Console.ReadKey();
```